# Netbook can not shutdown in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, shutdown, ubuntu-netbook

Why my netbook (with Ubuntu 12.10) can not do shutdown after I click shutdown feature on desktop tool bar. My netbook enter into new session after I click shutdown, rather than off. To shutdown my netbook, I forced to do it in harsh way: press on/off button.

What's the problem actually? And what is the solution?

Btw, before this problem happen, I added a new user in my netbook. Is there any correlation to my netbook shutdown problem?

Thanks for any help.

Regards,
Aswin Simatupang

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. It appeared after updating my system and adding a new user. I didn't know the solution yet, but I can give you advise to shut down with a command in terminal:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

In any way, it is not so harsh, as you do.